# CSS: stop text in unordered list from wrapping on ipad

Tags: css, ipad

I have the following unordered list:

```
<ul>
<li>some text</li>
<li style="overflow:hidden;white-space: nowrap;">some long text</li>
<li>other text</li>
<li>more text</li>
</ul>
```

which displays like the following in a normal browser

```
some text | some long text | other text | more text
```

However in an ipad it displays like this:

```
some text | some long | other text | more text
                 text
```

How do I prevent the li elements from wrapping on the ipad?

**EDIT:** If I add a large width to the style of "some long text" it displays like the following:

```
some text              | some long | other text | more text
                              text
```

If I change the text to some_long_text (making it all into one word) I see the following:

```
some text | some_long_text | other text | more text
```

so it seems like it is simply ignoring the white-space:nowrap; property.

Comment: @rOcKiNgRhO I tried that and the li container expanded but the text still wrapped (see edit above).

Comment: remove overflow:hidden, don't add any fixed width

Comment: You possibly might want to add li {width: auto;} that may fix it.